# Qt::ForegroundRole not applied on Linux when using qss style sheet

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qtstylesheets

I am offering the default style for Qt, but also some custom ones.
Those are applied by loading a qss resource file and applying it to to the application via qApp->setStyleSheet(). The default style is set by setStyleSheet("").

The style sheets themselves work fine.

Now I am using a custom event filter for some QComboBoxes to apply varying colors for some items. This done in the following way:

```
box->setItemData(i, QBrush(color), Qt::ForegroundRole);
```

On Windows, this works for both the default style and the style sheets loaded from qss files.
But on Linux, this works only for the default style. On the loaded style sheet, the color is simply not applied (all items have the same color).

I am unsure if this is a bug or if I am doing something wrong that just happens to work on Windows despite my mistake.

My OS is Kubuntu 14.04 (64bit). Qt is 5.2.1.
Due to the many files involved, I cannot really give a minimal example, but the project is [this](http://www.github.com/TheSHEEEP/SR5-Shaman) and it has no dependencies. The file in question would be [priorityeventfilter.cpp](https://github.com/TheSHEEEP/SR5-Shaman/blob/master/SR5-Shaman/ui/utils/priorityeventfilter.cpp).

Comment: What Linux, which qt, can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, I will add that.